# Html/CSS for mobiles that have 1080px wide browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport, mobile-browser

Currently working on a mobile app and have begun testing on different phones. The app is working on most phones but after testing on the Huawei p9 we ran into a few issues. The phone browser width is 1080px and default font size is 16px. This is causing our app to render at a very scale. We are currently using viewport and 'em' to code everything. Is there anything we can do to support browsers with such dimensions?

Comment: Could you post the test site URL also?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (width: 1080px) {

    font-size: 12px;

}
```

**This will work.**

Comment: I don't understand how this will work. If anything at all, I would have to set font-size to 48px just for the sizing to look similar. This would also cause every other device to have problems as everything will be 3 times too big.

Comment: You can set the preferences in the above stated media query